# How to Remove Duplicates from Comma seperated string in Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is a sample for my dataset.  I would like to write Spark SQL to change the itemlist with duplicate values to unique values so for example 'apple, banana, banana" will be come 'apple, banana'
I wrote the code here :

```sql
SELECT  ItemId, Date, concat_ws(',',collect_set(CAST(SPLIT(PointNameArray, ','),ARRAY<STRING>))) AS VarN
FROM    dataset
```

But I keep getting errors stating

> cannot resolve 'concat_ws(',',
> collect_set(split(dataset.`PointNameArray`, ',')))' due to data type
> mismatch: argument 2 requires (array or string) type, however,
> 'collect_set(split(dataset.`PointNameArray`, ','))' is of
> array<array>

[image]

The result for itemlist is

```
apple, banana
phone, computer
table, chair
```

So the table should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error :

> cannot resolve 'concat_ws(',',
> collect_set(split(dataset.PointNameArray, ',')))' due to data type
> mismatch: argument 2 requires (array or string) type, however,
> 'collect_set(split(dataset.PointNameArray, ','))' is of array

because `split` already returns an `array<string>` and `collect_set` is treating this entire array as a single entry  in the set, hence and `array<array<string>>`.

It should be noted that `collect_set` is an aggregate function that may be applied in a group by or as a window function on each row. Applying it on each row as a window function as is however will run the risk of the entire split array being considered as one element which is not the aim.

Moreover, when you `split` some sample data (`'apple, banana, banana`) by `,`, some may have spaces ( ) preceding the value and  `banana` is different from `banana`. To ensure we have unique values we can `trim` these.

Since you are using spark sql, the examples below will use spark-sql instead of the python/scala apis which could follow the same approach

**Sample Dataframe before**

```
+------+----------+---------------------+
|ItemId|Date      |itemList             |
+------+----------+---------------------+
|item1 |2019-01-01|apple, banana, banana|
+------+----------+---------------------+
```

**Proposed Code**

```sql
SELECT  
    ItemId, 
    Date, 
    concat_ws(',',collect_set(trim(isplit))) as VarN
FROM
    df
LATERAL VIEW explode(SPLIT(itemList,',')) as isplit
GROUP BY ItemId, Date
```

**Output After**

```
+------+----------+------------+
|ItemId|Date      |VarN        |
+------+----------+------------+
|item1 |2019-01-01|apple,banana|
+------+----------+------------+
```

In the sample code above the data is:

1. Split by `,` using `SPLIT(itemList,',')`
2. exploded into multiple rows using `explode(SPLIT(itemList,','))` in a lateral view outputing

```
+------+----------+-------+
|ItemId|Date      |isplit |
+------+----------+-------+
|item1 |2019-01-01|apple  |
|item1 |2019-01-01| banana|
|item1 |2019-01-01| banana|
+------+----------+-------+
```

3. The data is then trimmed to remove spaces using `trim(isplit)`
4. We then aggregate the data using `collect_set` which will provide our unique values, grouping on the other columns `ItemId, Date`. NB. If you have many columns you may group by on the unique column eg `ItemId` and simply use `MAX` on the others eg

```sql
SELECT  
    ItemId, 
    MAX(Date) as Date, 
    concat_ws(',',collect_set(trim(isplit))) as VarN
FROM
    df
LATERAL VIEW explode(SPLIT(itemList,',')) as isplit
GROUP BY ItemId
```

5. Finally we concatenate these values using `concat_ws`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `array_distinct` function not `collect_set`:

```py
spark.sql("""
SELECT  ItemId, 
        Date, 
        PointNameArray,
        concat_ws(',',array_distinct(split(PointNameArray, ','))) AS VarN
FROM    dataset
""").show(truncate=False)

#+------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+
#|ItemId|Date      |PointNameArray           |VarN          |
#+------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+
#|item1 |2019-01-01|apple,banana,apple,banana|apple,banana  |
#|item2 |2019-01-01|phone,computer,computer  |phone,computer|
#|item3 |2019-01-01|table,chair,table,chair  |table,chair   |
#+------+----------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: +1 for conciseness with `array_distinct` however, this does not give unique values when spaces are in the comma separated values eg `banana, banana, apple`, or `apple, banana, 
    banana`. How do you propose the op works with those cases?

Comment: @ggordon spaces can be handled easily by transforming the array: `transform(split(PointNameArray, ','), x -> trim(x))`.